# Error term conditional mean of 0. Linear regression

Tags: regression, assumptions

From my econometrics book i understand that the most important assumption of linear regression is that the error term has a conditional mean of 0, thus is independent of all the x values.

How can i test if this assumption is satisfied? (i do not have timeseries data)

All the best

Comment: Should i plot the residuals against the X-variables?

Comment: Yes, check whether the residuals depends on the predicted values of the model (they should not).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this please? Thanks a lot

Comment: In most implementations of linear regression, the estimated errors (residuals) have a mean of zero by design.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption $E(\xi|X)=0$ is called as *strong endogeneity*. It means that, there is no leakage of information posed by independent variables into the error term. This is, as the name implies, a very strong assumption and generally not possible. Therefore, we apply a softer version of it as:

\begin{align*}
E(\xi_i)=0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Cov(\xi_i,X_i)=0
\end{align*}

These conditions implies that the error mean is zero and there is no linear relationship between the errors and the independent variables, respectively. You can easily test these results. For the zero mean assumption, you can apply t-test to show that the residual mean does not significantly differ from zero while for the covariance condition, you can simply check correlation coefficients between the residuals and features, for each feature. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you mean strong/strict exogeneity.